# :not selected not working for parent

Tags: css

I try to select only elements where a parent one doesn't have a certain class.

So given:

```
<ul class="foo">
    <li class="one">one..</li>
    <li class="two">two</li>
    <li class="three">three</li>
</ul>

<ul>
    <li class="one">one..</li>
    <li class="two">two</li>
    <li class="three">three</li>
</ul>
```

and css:

```
:not(.foo) .one {
    color: red;
}
```

I expect only one 'one' element to be red. But both are. Here is the fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/633fnovy/2/

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are using a space seperator which will involve nested children.

If you think about it, all `.one` elements are a child of `body`, for example, which is `:not(.foo)`

Apply more specificity

```css
ul:not(.foo) .one {
  color: red;
}
```

```html
<ul class="foo">
  <li class="one">one..</li>
  <li class="two">two</li>
  <li class="three">three</li>
</ul>

<ul>
  <li class="one">one..</li>
  <li class="two">two</li>
  <li class="three">three</li>
</ul>
```

Answer (score 1):

Try adding the direct descendant selector `>`:

```css
:not(.foo) > .one {
    color: red;
}
```

```html
<ul class="foo">
    <li class="one">one..</li>
    <li class="two">two</li>
    <li class="three">three</li>
</ul>

<ul>
    <li class="one">one..</li>
    <li class="two">two</li>
    <li class="three">three</li>
</ul>
```

Comment: Meh, i'm too slow. +1 
Btw this is actually a [Child selector](http://www.w3.org/TR/CSS21/selector.html%23id-selectors#child-selectors)

Answer (score 0):

The way you are using:

```
:not(.foo) .one {
    color: red;
}
```

is similar:

```
*:not(.foo) .one {
    color: red;
}
```

You have to specify the content:

```css
ul:not(.foo) .one {
    color: red;
}
```

```html
<ul class="foo">
    <li class="one">one..</li>
    <li class="two">two</li>
    <li class="three">three</li>
</ul>

<ul>
    <li class="one">one..</li>
    <li class="two">two</li>
    <li class="three">three</li>
</ul>
```